# notify-send not working (in script) executed from udev

Tags: linux, usb, udev

I want a notification in desktop that a particular USB device is inserted.Hence the following is the udev rule.

```
KERNEL=="sd*",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb",ACTION=="add",RUN+="/home/username/Desktop/notify_script"
```

notify_script is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh  
su username -c 'notify-send "USB Inserted"'  
echo USB_inserted >> /home/username/Desktop/test_file
```

Problem :

The above script works perfectly if it is executed as root from command line but,  notify-send in script is not working if executed from udev.

Question:

How to make notify-send work from udev? or 
Is there any other way by which I can achieve notification ?
Is it possible to invoke any GUI from udev?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is, that the udev-rule will not run in any xorg-related environment per default, thus not knowing which DISPLAY to use. Therefore it will always fail, if You want to echo something into a terminal like a gnome-terminal for example. The script, which shall be executed on the udev-rule-match, must prior to any ui-related execution first export the DISPLAY.
This is done via

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I assume, that this also will be the problem, and notify-send will just run against the wall.

I am actually also playing with udev-rules, and I managed it to work, though i am acting as root, similar to my answer and this one found already here :

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80882/udev-running-a-shellscript-that-accesses-an-x-display

And also here

[Scripts launched from udev do not have DISPLAY access anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395027/scripts-launched-from-udev-do-not-have-display-access-anymore)

You might want also to check zenity. Very helpful for small notifications

Comment: it's not working a GUI display called by udev rules if not pre-run at least one time the same script directly from a terminal. you test it directly after a restart it doesn't display anything. but script get called... do you have idea? i have tested a script with zenity