# Open an lxterminal window via shell script triggered by udev rule

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, rule, udev

I'm trying to **start a python script** that **waits for user input** via a shell **script triggered** by a **UDEV rule**. After the input arrives the python script needs to make some database calls. I'm running into a couple different issues.

Here is the udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb" RUN+="/path/to/script.sh"
```

Issue #1 - I can't seem to get it to actually open the window. Here is what I have in script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
lxterminal -e /path/to/python_script.py
```

Here is the error I'm getting from udev:

```
'/path/to/script.sh'(err) '(lxterminal:4606): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: '
```

Here is another version of the shell script which actually ran, but wasn't visible, and crashed when checking for input. Guessing because I'll need to re-route stdin if I ever get the terminal to open? Script:

```
export DISPLAY=0:; bash -c /path/to/script.sh
```

Error:

```
(err) name = input('Enter your name')
(err) 'EOFError: EOF when reading a line'
```

If I get rid of the input, I get this error:

```
[4859] exit with return code 0
```

This answer makes it sound like this isn't possible, but this is programming anything is supposed to be possible! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119078/cannot-run-script-using-udev-rules

The end of this forum sounds like it's possible, but I'll need to use Zenity? https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=759389

Any info from someone that's more familiar with udev would be great!

Answer (score 1):

For Issue #1;

```
lxterminal --command "python -i /path/to/python_script.py"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately results in the same display warning :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the info I needed here: [Scripts launched from udev do not have DISPLAY access anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395027/scripts-launched-from-udev-do-not-have-display-access-anymore)

The script called by udev:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0; export XAUTHORITY='/var/run/lightdm/root/:0'; /path/to/python.py
```

Then inside my python.py script:

```
cmd = ["zenity", "--entry", "--title='title'", "--text='{}'".format(var)]
response = (subprocess.check_output(cmd)).decode("utf-8") # Decode to a string
```