# How to enable/disable screensaver from a program launched from /etc/rc.local

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want a Linux (Ubuntu) program to be able to enable and disable the console screen as needed.
When I run this in a ssh window I can use:

```
system("xset -display :0 dpms force on")
```

and

```
system("xset -display :0 dpms force off")
```

to get what I need; however if I launch it from `/etc/rc.local` that doesn't work.
Is there a good way to progammatically enable/disable the display?

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` runs when the system starts, probably before the X server has started. Or you are doing it from a long running program?

Comment: Its a long running program that starts in /etc/rc.local.  So the X server is certainly up and running.  I guess I don't know much about how applications hook to facilities provided by X; especially if being launched in rc.local (not from a terminal).

Comment: Then it may be a duplicate of [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20395027/scripts-launched-from-udev-do-not-have-display-access-anymore).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'm digging into that now.  It appears to still do some "X"-ish stuff just to wake up the console.  I guess my more fundamental question is "can't this be done without "X"?.

Comment: Well, I don't want to post this as the answer, but I did find a way around my problem... Instead of launching the program through /etc/rc.local, I do it with an autostart file under .config/autostart (for a localuser).  This allows the "xset" in my program run as expected.  Ideally, I'd still like to know how to do this without dependence on 'X'.

Comment: Well, obviously, you won't be able to use `xset` without an X server. Your problem with the X server is probably related to the authorization, as in the linked answer.

Comment: Yea of course.  But there's got to be a way to interact with the screen saver without the need for "xset" or the x server behind it.  Thanks...